# Warning: substr() expects parameter 2 to be long

Tags: php, string, web-scraping, substr

Why am I  getting this error while using `substr`:

> Warning: substr() expects parameter 2 to be long`

```
$url = "http://coast.x-matic.net/forums/categories/pso-news";

$ch = curl_init(); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); 
$webdata = (string) curl_exec($ch); 
curl_close($ch);

echo substr($webdata, "<a * class=\"title\">*</a>");
```

Comment: That is not the proper use of substr, maybe you want to use any other function here. For second option you should be giving it a length and not a string. See http://php.net/substr

Comment: I think you should use strstr().

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ref:  http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php

Syntax of substr : `string substr ( string $string , int $start [, int $length ] )`

`echo substr($webdata, 0, 5);` should be some thing like this.